# Android application to export data and settings of a given application

Tags: android, backup

I am looking for an Android application that can

- export data and settings of a given application

and if possible:

- can export several applications at once
- can export the .apk at the same time

I don't mind if the application required a rooted Android.

The application [App Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.appbackup) cannot backup data or settings of apps: it only backup the apk files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup)

- needs root
- export data and settings of a given application
- can export several applications at once
- can export the .apk at the same time
- tons of other features (especially in the pro version)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is [My Backup Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupRoot)

- Needs Root
- Can export Data
- Batch backup / restore
- Can export APK file

Answer (score 1):

A third option is **[AppMonster](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appmonster-free-backup-restore/de.android_telefonie.appmanager)**. With its latest version (just released this week) Grigory added support for backup/restore of app data. With AppMonster, you can...

- keep multiple versions of the same app (amount can be configured to only keep the latest X)
- manually backup/restore apps
- automatically backup new apps/versions when they are installed ([AppMonster Pro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/appmonster-pro-backup-restore/com.think_android.appmanagerpro) only)
- batch (re-)install (Pro: one-click; in the free version, you will have to approve each app separately)
- backup & restore app data (settings etc.)

It even includes several additional options not directly relevant to your question, such as delete/remove installed apps, display apps which carry ad-modules, display apps which can be moved to SD card, and more.

[image: AppMonster App List] [image: AppMonster Actions]
<sup>AppMonster: App List, Actions (source: *Google Play*; click images for larger variants)</sup>

I'm using AppMonster for years already (and don't want to miss it anymore). The dev is very responsive, and you get the feeling he really cares about his users (disclosure: through his app, I got to know Grigory personally meanwhile – but that doesn't mean I "glossed over" my recommendation here; I'm personally convinced of this app).